# Java WatchService and multithreading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I'm trying to build a process that will watch a list of directories (populated via JPA) and when a new file is detected in a folder a new thread is started to process that folder. A maximum of one thread should only be running per folder but multiple threads could run spanning different folders.

I've got that working somewhat with the below code but the issue I've found is.. say 1 out of 5 files have moved so far. A thread will be immediately made once the first is detected, the ProcessDatasource thread would then loop through the dir and make 1 file objects to process. In the mean time 4 files  would trigger the systemfilewatcher but would block due to a datasource thread already running on that folder. Now since filesystemwatcher will have already triggered when the files landed it won't run again which will leave those 4 files in limbo until another lands in that folder....

To solve this I thought if a file lands and a thread is already running I could call a method within the thread to add the file to the `List` of files it's currently processing but I'm struggling to do that when the threads are made dynamically in the below loop. Of course this could just be an awful way of doing all this so open to any suggestions.

```
private boolean checkThreadRunning(String threadName){
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for ( Thread t : threadSet){
        if ( t.getThreadGroup() == Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup() && t.getName().equals(threadName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void run(String... args) throws IOException {
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    List<DataSource> datasourceList = readDataSources(); // Load a list of DataSource objects into the datasourceList.

    Map<WatchKey, DataSource> keys = registerKeys(watchService, datasourceList);

    WatchKey key;
    while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
        DataSource dataSource = keys.get(key);

        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            String dataSourceName = dataSource.getDatasourceName();
            String threadName = "datasourceThread-" + dataSourceName;

            // Check if there is already a thread running on this datasource (folder)
            if (checkThreadRunning(threadName)) {
                System.out.println("Found another file for datasource " + dataSourceName + "but an instance is already running");
                // Need something here to pass this new file into the currently running thread to be processed...
            } else {
                // If not then start a thread which will work through processing the files within the folder.
                new Thread(new ProcessDatasource(threadName, dataSource)).start();
            }
        }
        key.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: *A maximum of one thread should only be running per folder*: could you please elaborate on this? Would it be possible to monitor new directories *and* files? Then you could have a mechanism to batch processing those files once a limit of files/directory is reached or a timeout is reached. Also, how many threads can be created with the current implementation?

Comment: A thread will be started when files are detected in a folder which processes them and loads them into a database sequentially, I only want one of these threads running per folder when files land in them, if that makes sense? I'm using the above code just to trigger the thread to say "I've found some files, start processing them" then the thread builds a file list and starts processing. In regards to how many threads... since each thread will likely be doing quite a bit of processing I'll likely put a limit on the max that can concurrently run.

Comment: Right - and how many (median, max) directories do you expect to be processed concurrently? Is all this part of batch process, or does latency matters? Are all files coming to a directory at the same time `t +/ delta` (where here the delta is what bothers you) or can new files appear at any time (i.e. at `t+t'` where `t'` is arbitrary e.g. 5 minutes, 2 hours etc.)?

Comment: Another upstream process moves the files in batches on a unix system. So they'll come in lots, probably 15 max should run at a time with the others waiting for a thread to free up.

Comment: ok - so maybe you could check once a `ProcessDatasource` task completes its work if additional files have come to the directory, then schedule a new round of processing for this directory? I don't have the code of `ProcessDatasource` so cannot see what could prevent you from doing that?

Comment: There's very little in ProcessDatasource at the moment, it just loops through the files in datasource.getDirectory, puts them in a list and echo's it back out before ending. That does sound like it could work though.. process as normal in the thread, then before ending just check if there's any new files.

Comment: The fact that a certain thread is responsible for a folder seems like an arbitrary and unnecessary requirement. If a new file pops up, create a task, submit it to a queue, and have worker threads handle these.

Comment: Sadly I don't think it's that simple, a folder represents a set of files which are loaded into the database in a particular way. This is done via an external table process. There's an external table per directory (file grouping/datasource), this loads files sequentially. If I had multiple files all going off at once they'd just be overwriting the file currently in that datasources external table.

Comment: I guess think of it as a thread is responsible for a datasource and one of the datasources properties is a folder and it's contents? A folder can only belong to one datasource.